# Why does ODBC connection from win2k (to ASA 8) stop working after moving workstation from LAN to VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, odbc, windows-2000

Background of my question is, from a local network we take one workstation, and connect it again via VPN from a home office.

I thought, a connection via VPN would be the same as if the computer were connected locally.

Establishing a VPN connection was not as easy as I thought.

After trying a lot of options the only possibility to connect the win2k workstation via VPN with the Fritz!Box router of our network was using the Shrew Soft VPN Client.

But I had to learn that first of all the name resolution of the servers was no more available and I had to edit `C:\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on the external workstation.

Probably finding ODBC servers is a similar problem.

We use an Adaptive Server Anywhere ASA 8.

While configuring the ODBC connection, I was missing the option to mention the IP where the server is running. There is only the name of the database requested, and in my case it could not been found through VPN.

Can anyone tell me how to tell the client where to find the server and the database?

A special situation to mention - although I don't think it does any matter: The Win2000 server and workstations run as Virtual box on Ubuntu-Systems.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what ODBC driver you're using for the connection, but I might suggest you try a different driver, like [my employer's offering](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sybase-st/), which *does* take an IP address for the target ASA.  The two-week free trial should be enough to confirm whether it does the job you need.

That said -- you should be able to adjust your VPN and/or overall networking setup, such that DNS hostname-to-IP resolution *does* work for the now-remote workstation.  My immediate hunch is that (some or all of) your Virtual Box guest OS are set to share the host OS' IP address (commonly labeled as "NAT" or "Network Address Translation") -- but what you probably need for the VPN to work properly is for all guest OS to have their own IP address, independent of the host OS (sometimes called "Bridged" or "Connected directly to the physical network").  These addresses could be dynamically assigned by DHCP, or you might need to manually configure this in each guest OS.  Exact steps vary enough that it's not worth putting specifics here.